# REST - maintaining "same result" vs. user-specific result

Tags: rest, get

In a REST API, after authentication a user receives an AccessToken, which is then sent along with every request. Server-side, the token is mapped to a UserID of that user.

Let's say I address the messages resource like this:

```
GET /user/123/messages
```

vs. accessing it in this way:

```
GET /messages/
```

and pulling the UserID from the AccessToken header.

Which way is more RESTful? I tend towards the first - it seems more readable and cachable, but are there other reasons as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first identifies a unique Resource, the second does not. If the meaning of the second URI depends on additional information (the session token), it doesn't identify anything. So only the first approach is RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

If user 456 makes your first get....what would u return?  If your second....?  I find my world to be "restish" and my services are idempotent per user.  Once authentication happens I put the users identity into http session (which tomcat gives me for free) and use services like /messages and /messages/99999.  The service impl then says "find message XXXX owned by the user in session.  The important part is to not store the rest data in session just who the user is.  Much easier then cookies...imho

Comment: REST is supposed to be stateless, so you shouldn't use sessions.